# Can't play video on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, reactjs, ipad, video, youtube

Dev Environment: https://cd-lb-2005177905.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/

I'm trying to do something as simple as get a video to work. If you click on the video image of the girl it plays - except if you're on iPad or iPhone and I don't know why.

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5video

Component (snippet):

```
type Props = { videoURL: String, posterImageURL: String };

const VideoJumbotron = ({ videoURL, posterImageURL }: Props) => (
  <div className={s.videoWrapper}>{console.log('posterImageURL', posterImageURL)}
    <Video
      poster={posterImageURL}
      controls={[]}
      onClick={function clickHandler(event) {
        event.persist();
        console.log(event, event.target);
        const video = event.target;
        try {
          if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
          } else {
            video.pause();
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }}
    >
      <source
        src={`${videoURL}.mp4`}
        type="video/mp4"
      />
      <source
        src={`${videoURL}.webm`}
        type="video/webm"
      />
    </Video>
  </div>
);
```

Parent component (snippet):

```
render() {
       ...
          <VideoJumbotron
            videoURL="/videos/clothes-doctor"
            posterImageURL="/videos/images/clothes-doctor.png"
          />
       ...
    );
  }
```

So, I've been through a few thoughts:

I wondered if it was about codecs and looked [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW1) - but it seems like they support what I have, which is `mp4 H.264, AAC` (I also have a webm version, but they won't use that).

I put it up to youtube and gave the youtube URL, but it seemed to try to download the whole thing (216.4Mb)...

I wondered if it was about Byte-range support (also known as content-range or partial-range support), so I did the cURL test:

```
curl --range 0-99 https://cd-lb-2005177905.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/videos/clothes-doctor.mp4 -o /dev/null -k
```

and got back:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   100  100   100    0     0    133      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2272
```

Which seems correct...

(One weird thing was when I viewed source in Chrome I get:

```
<video class="rh5v-DefaultPlayer_video" poster="/videos/images/clothes-doctor.png" data-reactid="76"><source src="/videos/clothes-doctor.mp4" type="video/mp4" data-reactid="77"/><source src="/videos/clothes-doctor.webm" type="video/webm" data-reactid="78"/></video>
```

but in firefox I get:

```
<video class="rh5v-DefaultPlayer_video" poster="/videos/images/clothes-doctor.png" data-reactid="94"><source src="/videos/clothes-doctor.mp4" type="video/webm" data-reactid="95"/></video>
```

^^ How can it have the different file extension? (Is it detecting original encoding??

Anyway, ANY help with this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Try `<video muted>` and see if that works. Safari on iOS really doesn't like autoplay videos / videos that play without an explicit user gesture. More Information on the policies [here](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/).

Comment: That might be a problem, as the video has a soundtrack that we want to be audible, but I'll have a look see...

Comment: It looks like your video is actually set up to autoplay inline in the HTML5 code. For iOS devices, since iOS 10 I think - before that it was not supported at all, this usually need to add the 'playsinline' attribute.

Comment: @Mick How is it configured to do that? Sorry, I don't understand. I've not set an attribute no it?!

Comment: Thing that really pisses me off: 'video.play() will return a Promise, which will be rejected if any of these conditions are not met.' I just logged that out: undefined. SO, it didn't do what you said it would do. Thanks Apple, love the bit where you're like 'OH, these developers are doing so much great stuff but it will all be for naught' <dr evil 1 finger pose>